# Synology RS818+ and 2 internet connections

Tags: networking, router, nas, synology-diskstation

We have an RS818+ in our small home based office. There are 2 incoming internet connections - one at 250/10 and one at 250/250. We run backups from the RS818+ to Backblaze B2. Obviously, I want to use the 250/250 connection for uploading them.

The router we are using (Pakedge RE-1) has dual WAN ports but only uses them for failover. Of course I tried with the 250/250 connection as the main with the slower connection as the failover, but the faster connection is having some issues (mainly noticeable on WiFi calling on cell phones - the cell signal is terrible so WiFi calling is a must) while the slower connection works fine.

I was hoping to be able to put the slower connection into the router and then put the faster connection directly into the RS818+ to use it for uploading to B2 (via Cloud Sync). I tried this, but I can't find how to get the RS818+ to use the LAN2 connection for uploading from Cloud Sync. I'm guessing something in traffic control should do it, but I haven't been able to figure out anything that works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure about this, as I can't test this myself...

With the direct internet connection hooked up as a second LAN interface to the Syno go into the network settings and select 1 of the network interfaces.
Under the Manage button you will find a "Service Order" entry.
Set the internet connected interface as the first interface for IPv4.

This should route outgoing connections made by the Syno on its own (like the backup) go out on the internet interface.
Responses to LAN requests coming in on the other interface should still be return via that same interface as they came in on.

Alternative method: Only viable if your local LAN is a single IP-subnet.
Give the LAN interface NO default gateway setting (not sure if you actually can do that with a Syno). That should route everything to the internet interface. (And still let the Syno answer to incoming traffic on the LAN interface.)

Comment: The "Service Order" solved it! Uploads are now running full speed on LAN2 and everything is still accessible over the network. Thank you!